# how to know from which search engine the visitors coming to my website ? PHP-JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, http, search-engine

Can I know which "search engine" the visitor used to be on my site?

For example:

- If the visitor searched for my website in google, when click on link from google to my website,  i need to know the search engine name, here is "google.com".
- The same if searched on yahoo , and click on my site link, i will get yahoo.com as a search engine.

It's possible?

Comment: If the information is available, it will probably be in the Referer.

Comment: i didn't find anythings :(

Comment: I just went to my website from a google search, and the referer was `https://www.google.com/`. I don't know why you didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the superglobal $_SERVER.

By testing and echoing out $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], you can capture the referring URL.

**Example code:**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) { 
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
}
```

Something to keep in mind from the manual.

> The address of the page (if any) which referred the user agent to the current page. This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.